# Mathematical formula returning incorrect values in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, formula, mathematical-optimization

I have a MySQL Stored Procedure where I have this formula -

chamt = CEIL((amount - (amount * ((percentage/100) * margin)/100)) * 100) / 100;

*(I have multiplied and divided the formula by 100 so as to get two decimal places always)*

---

**CASE 1 - Substituting the Values -**

chamt = CEIL((103.00 - (103.00 * ((100.00/100) * 2.70)/100)) * 100) / 100;

**Here, I am getting chamt as 100.22 which is absolutely correct.**

---

**CASE 2 - Substituting the Values -**

chamt = CEIL((200.00 - (200.00 * ((100.00/100) * 2.25)/100)) * 100) / 100;

**Here, I am getting chamt as 195.51 whereas it should be 195.50**

---

I am trying get out of this but unable to get the correct value in "Case 2". Members, please help me.

Comment: It works as expected on my local server

Comment: maybe show us the whole stored procedure, maybe the values for `amount`,`percentage` and `margin` aren't exactly as they seem.

Comment: @sectus This is working on local server for me also but not in the live environment.

Comment: @TinTran Values are exact.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when you work with real type numbers, it works with the decimals.

You know that 1/3 = 0.3333333333...

And (1/3)*3 = 1 (for you); But remember that PC's don't work with 1/3, they use the 0.3333333,
so when you do the multiplication (1/3)*3, the PC is doing this: (0.333333333)*3, and that gives you 0.9999999.

And 0.9999 != 1.

Maybe the type of the variable that you are using to do the operation is not the ideal for that application.

Comment: Aerojun, even if I apply your logic, I should get 195.50 in Case 2. I think thrs something more we are missing !!

Comment: @shailendra yes, it's called [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Comment: Then, you broke MySQL :( (jk). I'll check tomorrow the formula, i need to sleep